# Issue with MLRun Spark service start and impact all Jupyter notebooks

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, mlops, mlrun

I reconfigured Spark infrastructure in K8s (as part of MLRun/Iguazio platform) and after that, I got a lot of issues in level of services:

- Spark service (with information `Failed`)
- All jupyter notebooks (with information `Failed dependencies`)

and also general error/message:

```
Some services have not been successfully deployed. Check the services status as shown below.
```

See the print screen [image]

I changed only amount of RAM (1-30 GB RAM), vCPU (1-14) and Replicas (3).

Did you get the similar issue and how to avoid the situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was human mistake, the solution was easy and the key problem was in Spark service configuration (I configured extremely small vCPU values and it generated timeouts for Spark service):

- I used setting vCPU in the range 1-14 but I used default units `millicpu` (not cpu)
- After setup correct units `cpu` and restart of Spark service, everything was fine.

Wrong setting [image]

Correct setting [image]